# eclipse add command button to property view

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there any way to add a command button to the eclipse property view?  It seems as if the only things you can add to it are:

PropertyDescriptor - read-only property

TextPropertyDescriptor - edits with a TextCellEditor

CheckboxPropertyDescriptor - edits with a CheckboxCellEditor

ComboBoxPropertyDescriptor - edits with a ComboBoxCellEditor

ColorPropertyDescriptor - edits with a ColorCellEditor

I'd like to create a button that opens a dialog window to configure additional properties.